# How to specify Spring Servlet with Atmosphere in main()

Tags: java, spring, sockets, atmosphere

Currently I'm implementing atmosphere into my main() method like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

    //enable web socket support
    final WebSocketAddOn addon = new WebSocketAddOn();
    for (NetworkListener listener : server.getListeners()) {
        listener.registerAddOn(addon);

        //if false, local files (html, etc.) can be modified without restarting the server
        //@todo experiment with this setting in production vs development
        listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);
    }

    //add jersey servlet support
    ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new ServletContainer());
    //jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "come.fettergroup.production.queue.resources");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");

    //add atmosphere servlet support
    ServletRegistration atmosphereServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", new AtmosphereServlet());
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType", "application/json");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
```

How can I take this XML file and accomplish the same thing, but in the above code?

```
<atmosphere-handlers>
    <atmosphere-handler context-root="/api" class-name="org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor">
        <property name="servletClassName"
                  value="com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet" />
    </atmosphere-handler>
</atmosphere-handlers>
```

I've looked into assigning handlers to Atmosphere, but it requires an instance of  `AtmosphereFramework` which I'm unable to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your AtmosphereHandler by doing:

```
AtmosphereServlet s = new AtmosphereServlet();
AtmosphereFramework f = s.framework();

ReflectorServletProcessor r = new ReflectorServletProcessor();
r.setServletClassName("com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet");

f.addAtmosphereHandler("/api/*", r);

ServletRegistration atmosphereServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", s);
```

Thanks for filling the issue BTW, will improve FAQ

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: Awesome, though it looks like `setServletClassName()` is what I need instead of `setServletClass()` because it's deprecated